# Make two y axis line up in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting some hardness data and I want to display two different hardness scales.  One scale has no limits, while the other one does.  In the vickers hardness scale, there is no limit, but the Rockwell C scale is not valid below 20.  How can I make the scales line up?  So far my plan was to plot the vickers data, then filter it so that nothing below 20 is in there (the report from the testing machine assigns it as 0).  I then plotted the Rockwell data but was going to hide the points and assign it to a second y axis.  I have had no problem plotting but I cant get the two axis' to line up right.  I can force them to line up at one point, but the scaling is off so they start to fall apart away from where I lined them up.

The code I used to do that I found from another question is:

```
def align_yaxis(ax1, v1, ax2, v2):
"""adjust ax2 ylimit so that v2 in ax2 is aligned to v1 in ax1"""
_, y1 = ax1.transData.transform((0, v1))
_, y2 = ax2.transData.transform((0, v2))
inv = ax2.transData.inverted()
_, dy = inv.transform((0, 0)) - inv.transform((0, y1-y2))
miny, maxy = ax2.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylim(miny+dy, maxy+dy)
```

I can't upload images yet, but here is a link to an example plot.  [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWxTN.png)

What I did was line up Vickers 392 with HRC 40. But at the bottom, HRC 20 does not equal 200, it should equal 238. For this example, I turned on the HRC markers as x's

Edit:  Here is the code I use to generate the  plots but with hard coded data set.

```
xData = [[-0.00107, 0.014, 0.0299, 0.044, 0.0584, 0.0744, 0.089, 0.104, 0.119, 0.135, 0.149,   0.164, 0.179, 0.194, 0.208, 0.224, 0.239, 0.254, 0.269, 0.284, 0.299, 0.314, 0.329, 0.344, 0.359, 0.372, 0.389, 0.404, 0.419, 0.434, 0.449, 0.464, 0.479, 0.494, 0.509, 0.524, 0.539, 0.554, 0.569, 0.584, 0.599, 0.614, 0.629, 0.644, 0.659, 0.674, 0.689, 0.704, 0.719, 0.734, 0.749, 0.764, 0.779, 0.794, 0.809, 0.824, 0.839]]

yData = [[244.0, 225.0, 203.0, 209.0, 214.0, 220.0, 215.0, 220.0, 217.0, 218.0, 220.0, 220.0, 215.0, 221.0, 213.0, 216.0, 221.0, 222.0, 220.0, 216.0, 223.0, 219.0, 216.0, 308.0, 327.0, 338.0, 347.0, 334.0, 314.0, 383.0, 360.0, 323.0, 306.0, 213.0, 223.0, 223.0, 222.0, 217.0, 215.0, 219.0, 214.0, 221.0, 217.0, 214.0, 217.0, 214.0, 219.0, 211.0, 218.0, 213.0, 216.0, 218.0, 213.0, 222.0, 214.0, 227.0, 251.0]]

hrcX = [[-0.00107, 0.344, 0.359, 0.372, 0.389, 0.404, 0.419, 0.434, 0.449, 0.464, 0.479, 0.839]]

hrcY = [[21.2, 30.7, 33.0, 34.2, 35.3, 33.8, 31.5, 39.1, 36.6, 32.6, 30.5, 22.5]]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(xData[t],yData[t], '--o')
ax2.plot(hrcX[t], hrcY[t], 'x')
ax1.set_ylabel('Vickers Hardness')
ax1.set_xlabel('Distance (in)')
ax2.set_ylabel('HRC')
align_yaxis(ax1,392,ax2,40)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The main problem here seems to be that the conversion between the two scales (vickers and rockwell) is not linear, is that correct? ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardness_comparison))

Answer (score 2):

You could just set the limits manually and then make sure that you have no ticks below 20 on the second y axis:

```
ax1.set_ylim([200, 392])
ax2.set_ylim([20*200/238.,40])
ax2.set_yticks([20, 25, 30, 35, 40])
```

Comment: If I do that, then there is data that is not shown that is below 238 on the Vickers scale.

Comment: I would not use `set_yticks` as it decoupels your labels form the values.

Comment: that did work better, thanks. The data is not exactly linear because I think there is some rounding.  But if the hrc 20 & 40 points line up then it should be pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

So to get around my problem, I used axhlines at the appropriate y values and labeled them with text.  So I basically just made my own scale and did not let matplotlib make it for me.